# C++: Type independent sorting does not work

Tags: c++

I would appreciate if someone helped me to solve the problem related to the sorting. I am aiming to have a class with a sorting method. The method should accept any kind of array types (using: template  etc) and print the sorted array out.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
 
template <typename T> 
class Array {

    private:
        T* ptr;
        int size;
    
    public:
        Array(T arr[], int s);
        void SortAll();
        void print();
};
 
template <typename T> 
Array<T>::Array(T arr[], int s) {

    ptr = new T[s];
    size = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr[i];
}
 
template <typename T> 
void Array<T>::SortAll() {

    int n = sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]);

    sort(ptr, ptr + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ptr); i++)
        cout << " " << (ptr[i]);
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T> void Array<T>::print() {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << " " << *(ptr + i);
    cout << endl;
}
 
int main() {
    int intArr[5] = { 3, 1, 2, 5, 4 };
    char charArr[5] = { 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e' };
    
    Array<int> intTestArray = Array<int>(intArr, 5);
    intTestArray.print();
    intTestArray.SortAll();

    Array<char> charTestArray = Array<char>(charArr, 5);
    charTestArray.print();
    charTestArray.SortAll();

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
 3 1 2 5 4

 1 2 3 4 5 0 1041 0

 d b a c e

    a b c d e
```

I should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5

a b c d e
```

I have gone though several manuals and documents but I do not find any way out.

Thanks in advance!

:-)

Comment: Unrelated, but your may be interested in reading [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165) and [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/11082165)

Comment: You're using `size` in `print()`, and `sizeof(...)` in `SortAll()`. Why the discrepancy? If you print the result of `sizeof(...)`, you'll see that it's not what you expected.

Comment: `sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0])` - by your own variable names, you seem to know that `ptr` is a _pointer_ and not an _array_ type. The size of a pointer divided by the size of `T` doesn't have any useful meaning.

Comment: Adding to @Brian61354270s comment, you also make a member variable `size`. Why not just use that for the size?

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for you comments. I try to implement your ideas later on :-)